# How to run Multiple Instances of Elasticsearch on Single Node

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have found some answers to this question on StackOverflow but those are a bit old. I need to configure multiple instances with the latest version (7.9.3)  of `elasticsearch`  and couldn't find any answers which are compatible with that.

**Step 01**

Set environment variable on windows

`ES_HOME` = `../elasticsearch`

`ES_PATH_CONF` = `../elastcisearch/config`

**Step 02**

created `elasticsearch_1.yml` and `elastcsearch_2.yml` config files

**Steo 03**

run the `elasticsearch.bat` with the config file

```
 bin/elasticsearch -Des.config=$ES_HOME/config/elasticsearch.1.yml
```

then the following error will be thrown

```
  ERROR: D is not a recognized option
```

**Note - I know that the above approach is a bit old and how to do the above steps with the current (7.9) version**

Comment: Do you also want all these ES installations to be a part of same ES cluster??

Comment: it depends on the time, some time needs and sometimes not

Comment: Ok, will add the details on how to add them in a cluster as well, were u able to start both ES using my below config ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to give -D option and don't create two config file in a single ES installation folder.

Instead, just change the `elasticsearch.config` in two ES installation folder and run them on separate ports.

ES-1 `elasticsearch.config`

```
http.port: 9200
```

ES-2 `elasticsearch.config`

```
http.port: 9500
```

And after this, simply start both the node, one by one from using `bin/elasticsearch` command.

Comment: In that case, should I have to create two config directories?

Comment: @NafazBenzema, no you need to have two separate ES installation directory, if you are using tarball installation, just create a clone of that directory and change the `elasticsearch.yml`.

Comment: if I use 10 instances then should I need 10 ES installation directories?

Comment: @NafazBenzema yes, in this case, but why you want to run 10 ES instances on a single system??

Comment: no need, I asked as an example and can you please explain how to use the tarball installation

Comment: I have found this one `bin/elasticsearch -Des.config=$ES_HOME/config/elasticsearch.1.yml` which has been posted 3 years ago.  in this case, we don't need multiple ES install directories am I right?. But in the present way, we need more resources than the previous one

Comment: @NafazBenzema you can refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/zip-targz.html for tarball installation but you don't need this if you already have the ES installation directory, so just need to copy and give another name like `es-2` etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225194/discussion-between-elasticsearch-ninja-and-nafazbenzema).