# Install two versions of Elasticsearch on my machine

Tags: elasticsearch, service, windows-10, upgrade

There's a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65033430/595305) from 2020. I simply can't understand what those guys are talking about.

This is on a W10 box. ES (7.10.2) is currently running on localhost:9200. I need to upgrade. When I attempted to upgrade to 7.16.3 some time ago a regression occurred, reported by me and acknowledged by Elasticsearch HQ, which hopefully will now have been corrected. But I absolutely need to do some testing to ensure that my stuff won't break, hence two versions, one on another localhost port.

I have just downloaded the latest stable release, 8.6.2 and unzipped the .zip. Under directory ...\ElasticSearch\elasticsearch-8.6.2\config there is no file "elasticsearch.config", for example.

At the other SO question the guy with the answer says: "Instead, just change the elasticsearch.config in two ES installation folder and run them on separate ports." I suppose "two ES installation folder" means "in the second ES installation folder". But I'm none the wiser about what to do next.

I want 8.6.2 to run as a W10 service, for example at localhost:9500.

Answer (score -1):

## Tldr;

All you need is to start multiple instances:

- Binded on different ports
- Writing to different folder

## Explanation

In theory you would just need to have:

- distinct data folder
- distinct config folder
- distinct ports (configured in the `elasticsearch.yml` in the config folder)

and then run the `elasticsearch.bat` a much as needed giving the right `ES_PATH_CONF` for each instances.

## Container

Using docker you could easily run multiple instances.

```
docker run --name es01 -p 9201:9200 -v elasticsearch_7.10.2.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.2

docker run --name es02 -p 9202:9200 -v elasticsearch_7.16.3.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.16.3
```

## Warning

This is not a great idea as each instances are going to compete for the same resources. (Ram / CPU / Io).
Please do not try to co localise multiple instance on a same node without knowing what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to use Docker. I changed elasticsearch.yml to have, uncommented,  "http.port: 9500" and then ran elasticsearch.bat. Failed: "java.lang.RuntimeException: org.elasticsearch.cli.UserException: will not overwrite keystore at [D:\apps\ElasticSearch\elasticsearch-7.10.2\config\elasticsearch.keystore], because this incurs changing the file owner". Indeed, I don't want it to "overwrite" anything!

Comment: I also tried setting ES_PATH_CONF to various reasonable directories (including "...\config"). Each time this led to a "Usage" complaint when I tried running elasticsearch.bat. I also tried stopping the current ES service (7.10.2). Same problems.